# What is the probability that an $n$-team round robin tournament will have a "winner"?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

I found this link in OEIS A000568

Peter Steinbach, [Field Guide to Simple Graphs, Volume 4](https://oeis.org/A000664/a000664_11.pdf), Part 11 (For Volumes 1, 2, 3, 4 of this book see A000088, A008406, A000055, A000664, respectively.)

In Table 8.1 the author gives the "Condorcet" probability as $\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ without any explanation.

A tournament has a winner if there is exactly one team that has strictly more victories than any other team.  In other words, the scoring sequence has a unique maximum.

Comment: Your link is not working.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Sorry about that.  If you want to read the article you can go to OEIS A000568 and click on the link provided.

Comment: The only question you ask is in the title (it's always best to ask questions in the body, not just the title), and you answer that question yourself. Are you asking for a proof? a hint for a proof? a reference to a published proof?

Comment: Link working now.  But I would have thought you wanted [OEIS A006125](https://oeis.org/A006125) as your denominator with labelled outcomes

Comment: The "Condorcet" probability of $\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ is the probability that any of the $n$ teams wins all its $n-1$ matches.  The probability you are asking for is much larger than this

Comment: @Henry.  Yes the denominator is $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$.  Thanks for clarifying what is meant by Condorcet probability.  This makes sense.

Comment: @Greg.  OK Thanks.  My question is:  What is the probability that a tournament will have a winner.  From comment by Henry, we see that this is not the same as the Condorcet probability given in the link.

Comment: Simulation suggests the probability is not a monotonic function at least for small $n$, though I would have intuitively guessed it would tend to increase with $n$.  For $n=2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ I seem to get about $1.00, 0.75,0.50,0.59, 0.63,0.58,0.60,0.61$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption each game is independent of the others and each teams has a probability $\frac12$ of winning each game, independently of what happens in other games.  Real tournaments are not like that.

Sometimes you do some work and them find somebody else has done it earlier and better.  So skip below the line to find a better answer, as what follows is a description of what I did.

I commented

> Simulation suggests the probability is not a monotonic function at least for small $n$, though I would have intuitively guessed it would tend to increase with $n$. For $n=2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ I seem to get about $1.00,0.75,0.50,0.59,0.63,0.58,0.60,0.61$

This came from the following R code:

```
onewinner <- function(n){
  mat0 <- matrix(rbinom(n^2,1,1/2), ncol=n)
  mat1 <- mat0 * upper.tri(mat0, diag=FALSE)
  sortedwins <- sort(rowSums(mat1) - colSums(mat1) + (1:n) - 1)
  return(sortedwins[n] > sortedwins[n-1])
  }
```

and for example with $n=7$ and $10^5$ simulations, or with $n=100$ and $10^4$ simulations

```
set.seed(2022)
mean(replicate(10^5, onewinner(7)))
# 0.57939
mean(replicate(10^4, onewinner(100)))
# 0.7788
```

Simulation is not necessary fro small $n$.  It is possible to work out exact values, as with the following R code:

```
n <- 1
newx <- 0
newways <- 1
sortdigits <- function(n){
  as.numeric(paste(sort(strsplit(as.character(n),"")[[1]]),collapse=""))
  }
while(n < 10){
  n <- n+1
  x <- newx
  ways <- newways
  for (i in 0:(n-2)){
    x <- c(x+10^i,x+10^(n-1))
    }
  ways <- rep(ways,2^(n-1))
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    x[i] <- sortdigits(x[i])
    }
  newx <- unique(x)
  newways <- numeric(length(newx))
  for (i in 1:length(newx)){
    newways[i] <- sum(ways[x == newx[i]])
    }
  sum(newways[(newx %% 100) %% 11 > 0]) /  sum(newways)
  print(c(n,length(newx),sum(newways[(newx %% 100) %% 11 > 0]), sum(newways)))
  print(sum(newways[(newx %% 100) %% 11 > 0]) /  sum(newways))
  }
```

and that gives the following numbers

```
 n uniquepatterns singlewinners allpatterns probability-singlewinners
 2       1                   2            2          1
 3       2                   6            8          0.75
 4       4                  32           64          0.5
 5       9                 600         1024          0.5859375
 6      22               20544        32768          0.6269531
 7      59             1218224      2097152          0.5808945
 8     167           160241152    268435456          0.5969448
 9     490         42129744768  68719476736          0.6130685
10    1486        2.129323e+13 3.518437e+13          0.6051900
```

---

These sequences appear in OEIS: the unique patterns are [OEIS A000571](https://oeis.org/A000571) though they are not equally likely, the number of possibilities with a single winner is [OEIS A013976](https://oeis.org/A013976), and the total number of possibilities of $2^{n(n-1)/2}$ is [OEIS A006125](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLG9a.png).  Since Andrew Howroyd has worked out the numbers to $n=20$ in  OEIS A013976 with a PARI program though no stated formula, it is worth recording the probabilities these imply:

```
n   probability
1   1
2   1
3   0.75
4   0.5
5   0.58594
6   0.62695
7   0.58089
8   0.59694
9   0.61307
10  0.60519
11  0.61675
12  0.62287
13  0.62437
14  0.63265
15  0.63606
16  0.64045
17  0.64591
18  0.64913
19  0.65379
20  0.65759
```

As I commented initially, this is not monotonic for small $n$ but graphed looks like
[image: this]

Comment: OK  Thanks!  Just to clarify, you're simulations suggest that for n=100 the desired probability is about 78%.  Right?  I am surprised that you can run simulations for n=100.  Do you have any other evidence (i.e. trials for n > 100) that might suggest that the probability goes to 1 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @geoffrey Since it is a simulation, probably better to say $77\%-79\%$ when $n=100$.  If you are prepared to wait a few minutes, then you can also do `set.seed(2022); mean(replicate(10^3, onewinner(1000)))` which gives `0.891` perhaps better described as $87\%-91\%$, so still increasing when $n=1000$.  I would not push it further than this due to time and memory constraints, and if you wanted to do so then it would be worth finding a more efficient simulation.